# Sitemap on multiple webserver

Tags: sitemap

If I have two webserver serving the same domain. Is it possible to have sitemap1.xml on server1 and sitemap2.xml on server2? sitemap1 and sitemap2 will have different dynamic contents. Will search engines be able to find and index them?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure they can find both sitemaps, make sure they are declared in your `robots.txt` file:

```
sitemap: http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap1.xml
sitemap: http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap2.xml
```

See a summary I [maintain](https://seosummaries.com/expertise/robots-txt-implementation-seo.html) for more information.